# Infinite back functionality like Instagram

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Lets suppose, in an app there is ViewProfile Component, we open this Component and we see list of users who like this opened profile. We click one AnotherUser34 (With same ViewProfile Component) and see his profile and users who like him, and again we click/open 91AnotherUser from there, and we open 10 more profiles and so on. How to achive back functionality for each this? When I press back on ViewProfile Component, it goes back to Tabbar Component. I want it to go back similar way components are opened.

I want to have Instagram like back functionality.

Please suggest, a small hint will do the job, Thanks.

Below is my the Scene structure ( Specifically : https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake/blob/master/src/snowflake.js )

```
<Router>
<Scene  key='root' hideNavBar>
<Scene key='login'/>
<Scene key='register'/>
<Scene key='Tabbar'>
    <Scene key='Main'>
        <Scene key='ViewProfile'/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key='Nav2'/>
    <Scene key='NavMenu3'/>
    <Scene key='NavMenu4'/>
</Scene>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exact use case for 'clone' scenes.

From 
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md:

> Scenes marked with clone will be treated as templates and cloned into the current scene's parent when pushed. See example.

Comment: If the person who develope the library says this is the way to go, who am I to say it's not  :)
BTW is there any downside to my code, in performance or anything else?
Because if there is I think is time for me to review my code. :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this using Type "push" functionality.

What this does, is when you call Actions.ViewProfile(), it add's to the navigation stack.

I'm not 100% sure, and I can't test it right now. But I think it will work.

You can check the [docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/v3/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md) here. (Go to Scene in docs.)

```
 <Router>
    <Scene  key='root' hideNavBar>
    <Scene key='login'/>
    <Scene key='register'/>
    <Scene key='Tabbar'>
        <Scene key='Main'>
            <Scene key='ViewProfile' type="push"/>
        </Scene>
        <Scene key='Nav2'/>
        <Scene key='NavMenu3'/>
        <Scene key='NavMenu4'/>
    </Scene>
    </Router>
```

If you want programmatically:

```
Actions.ViewProfile({type: 'push'});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your solution also works perfectly.